# MaterialAlertDialogBuilder doesn't display margins for title and message

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, android-styles, material-components-android

I'm not really sure whether this is a bug, but I haven't found anyone online who has experienced this issue, so I wanted to try here first.

I'm trying to call a simple Material Alert Dialog in my Fragment with the following code:

```
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
        .setTitle("Dialog")
        .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
        .show()
```

The context is the basic `getContext()`.
However what I get displayed is the following:

[image: picture of wrong looking dialog]

Which obviously doesn't look right. I'm also using `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` as my parent theme and have `<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>` included in my style.

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Comment: It seems a bug. Which version of material components library you are using?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I'm using the 1.2 alpha 04 but I tried with a rc02 1.1 (stable release) and it didn't work either

Comment: Very strange. It seems that dialogPreferredPadding is set to 0dp